# View Recycle Bin data In Lightning

Tags: lightning

A user does not have the 'Modify All Data' permission. This user has deleted data some records. The user can see these deleted records in the recycle bin in Salesforce Classic, but not in Lightning. The bin is accessible in Lightning but no records show. Can someone explain this behaviour?

[image: Classic]

[image: Lightning]

Comment: Are you sure lightning bin is enabled in org? Can you share your OrgId so I can check on it

Comment: It is enabled. All users are working in Lightning. I included screenshots to illustrate. Same user but discrepancies between LEX and Classic.

Comment: In Classic is this behaviour under myrecyclebin or Allrecyclebin

Comment: Under myrecyclebin.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the ListView to Org Recycle Bin if you have the correct access:

[Here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.recycle_bin_manage.htm&type=5) is the documentation on what "correct access" means.

[image]

Comment: Due to Sharing settings, users must only see their own data. So the 'Org Recycle Bin' list view is not an available (see screenshot).

Comment: Then it is working as expected.

Comment: The expected behaviour is that SF Lightning and classic displays the same records in the recycle bin, given the same user.